# Difference between properties File, Yaml & Json?

Tags: selenium

I'm a beginner in software testing. I'm working with selenium with page object design patterns. I want to keep the test data separately, but i'm confusing how to do it.
I want to know the difference between the usage of properties file, yaml, json.
Which is most useful in software testing?

Which should I choose yaml, properties file, or json. So I need to keep the test data separately in json or properties file or yaml. Which is more people using nowadays ? As a tester using yaml, json and properties file is knowiing well. or following as particular pattern which is more easier. whats your suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML** (Extensible Markup Language) is flexible and powerful markup capabilities. It is often used in configuration and preference files like those used for the Eclipse IDE. Most Web browsers have XML viewers, although XML is designed for structured data, making it a bit like looking at the internals of a database.

**JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)** is used with JavaScript, of course. It will be familiar to Web developers that use it for client/server communication.

**YAML** stands for YAML Ain’t Markup Language. It uses line and whitespace delimiters instead of explicitly marked blocks that could span one or more lines like XML and JSON. This approach is used in many programming languages, such as Python.

**So it comes down to YAML or JSON**-

Technically YAML is a superset of JSON. That is, in theory at least, a YAML parser can understand JSON, but not necessarily the other way around.

In general, there are certain things I like about YAML that are not available in JSON.

1) YAML is visually easier to look at. In fact the YAML homepage is itself valid YAML, yet it is easy for a human to read.

2)YAML has the ability to reference other items within a YAML file using "anchors." Thus it can handle relational information as one might find in a MySQL database.

3)YAML is more robust about embedding other serialization formats such as JSON or XML within a YAML file.

4)YAML, depending on how you use it, can be more readable than JSON

5)JSON is often faster and is probably still interoperable with more systems

6)Duplicate keys, which are potentially valid JSON, are definitely invalid YAML.

7)YAML has a ton of features, including comments and relational anchors. YAML syntax is accordingly quite complex, and can be hard to understand.

8)YAML can be used, directly, for complex tasks like grammar definitions, and is often a better choice than inventing a new language.

**If you don't need any features which YAML has and JSON doesn't, I would prefer JSON because it is very simple and is widely supported (has a lot of libraries in many languages). YAML is more complex and has less support. I don't think the parsing speed or memory use will be very much different, and maybe not a big part of your program's performance.But JSON is the winner for performance (if relevant) and interoperability. YAML is better for human-maintained files.So basically use as per your requirements not what most people are using.**

Comment: As a tester using yaml, json and properties file is knowiing well. or following as particular pattern which is more easier. whats your suggestion ?

Comment: I think using easier pattern is very relative. It is better to know properties of YAML,JSON and XML and use them as per requirement.

Comment: Please upvote and click the tick option if you are satisfied with the answer.
Thanks

Comment: I could not able to upvote because less than 15 reputation. Any way thanks for the support

Comment: You are Welcome and All the Very Best for Future. :)